# How to strictly type abstract function implementations typescript

Tags: typescript

Say I have these two classes

```
abstract class Config {
    abstract setName(name: string);
}

class MyConfig extends Config {
    setName(name) {
         // set name.
    }
}
```

The `name` param in `MyConfig` will by of type `any`. What is the point on typing abstract functions if their types don't get passed down? Is there any way to make it typed without touching the `MyConfig` class? I want to make a config for a third party tool and can't expect users to type abstract function params even though they should.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the point on typing abstract functions if their types don't get passed down?

The point of typing abstract functions, is to help those users that opt-in to static type checking. In those cases, static type checking may prevent a bug, by complaining about this:

```
// compiler: Class 'MyConfig' incorrectly extends base class 'Config'.
class MyConfig extends Config {
    setName(name: number) {

    }
}
```

For users that do not opt-in to static type checking, you're right. The `name` param in `MyConfig` will be of type `any`, the compiler will not complain about types, and your typing of the abstraction function is useless.

There is no way to force TypeScript users to opt-in to static type checking, because there is no way to prevent users from using `any`. That is by design.

Suggestion: accept that some users will opt-in to static type checking and others will not. Provide types for those that do.